# How to parse csv file and compute stats based on that data

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, pandas

I have a task which requires me to make a program in python that reads a text file which has information about people (name, weight and height).

Then I need the program to ask for the user to enter a name then look for that name in the text file and print out the line which includes that name and the person's height and weight.

Then the program has to work out the average weight of the people and average height.

The text file is:

```
James,73,1.82,M
Peter,78,1.80,M
Jay,90,1.90,M
Beth,65,1.53.F
Mags,66,1.50,F
Joy,62,1.34,F
```

So far I have this code which prints out the line using the name that has been typed by the user but I don't know to assign the heights and the weights:

```
search = input("Who's information would you like to find?")
with open("HeightAndWeight.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        if search in line:
            print(line)
```

Comment: look into `str.split`.

Comment: You should try to split the tasks into small sub-problems. For example, have you tried to calculate average values from a plain list of numbers? You should read up on reading csv files in python, and generator expressions / list comprehensions. Alternatively have a look into the `pandas` library which probably provides all of the functionality you need. Finally (better: firstly), get familiar with the language. Maybe walk through a basic tutorial.

Comment: I have made a program that calculates an average from a plan list of numbers I am just having problems with spliting the lines up and only taking the numbers needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
splitted_line = line.split(',', 4)
```

to split the line you just found into four parts, using the comma `,` as a delimiter. You then can get the first part (the name) with `splitted_line[0]`, the second part (age) with `splitted_line[1]` and so on. So, to print out the persons name, height and weight:

```
print('The person %s is %s years old and %s meters tall.' % (splitted_line[0], splitted_line[1], splitted_line[2]))
```

To get the average on height and age, you need to know how many entries are in your file, and then just add up age and height and divide it by the number of entries/persons. The whole thing would look like:

```
search = input("Who's information would you like to find?")
total = 0
age = 0
height = 0
with open("HeightAndWeight.txt", "r") as f:
for line in f:
    total += 1
    splitted_line = line.split(',', 4)
    age += int(splitted_line[1])
    height += int(splitted_line[2]) 
    if search in line:
        print('The person %s is %s years old and %s meters tall.' % (splitted_line[0], splitted_line[1], splitted_line[2]))
average_age = age / total
average_height = height / total
```

That's one straightforward way to do it, and hopefully easy to understand as well.

Comment: When writing this answer there was no csv mentioned in the title, maybe you're expected to use the `csv` lib in this case.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help this did work and it was simple to understand.

Comment: Your're welcome, if you feel like accepting this as the answer, I wouldn't mind

Answer (score 4):

Using the `pandas` library as suggested, you can do as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('people.txt', header=None, index_col=0)
df.columns = ['weight', 'height', 'sex']
print(df)

       weight  height sex
0                        
James      73    1.82   M
Peter      78    1.80   M
Jay        90    1.90   M
Beth       65    1.53   F
Mags       66    1.50   F
Joy        62    1.34   F

print(df.mean())

weight    72.333333
height     1.648333
```

Comment: Since this is an assignment, I dont think something like Panda will be accepted ;)

Comment: As this site is not only there to provide students solutions to their homework assignments, but to also help others solve similar problems, I think this answer is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 3):

You could use Python's built in [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#module-csv) module to split each line in the file into a list of columns as follows:

```
import csv

with open('HeightAndWeight.txt', 'rb') as f_input:
    csv_input = csv.reader(f_input)
    total_weight = 0
    total_height = 0

    for index, row in enumerate(csv_input, start=1):
        total_weight += float(row[1])
        total_height += float(row[2])

    print "Average weight: {:.2f}".format(total_weight / index)
    print "Average height: {:.2f}".format(total_height / index)
```

This would display the following output:

```
Average weight: 72.33
Average height: 1.65
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer is actually in your question's title : use the [standard lib's `csv` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) to parse your file

Comment: I did not write that title, I am new to this so I think it may have been edited by someone else.

Answer (score 0):

```
search = input("Who's information would you like to find?")
heights = []
weights = []
with open("HeightAndWeight.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        if search in line:
            print(line)
            heights.append(int(line.split(',')[2]))
            weights.append(int(line.split(',')[1]))
# your calculation stuff
```